# Google Chrome Extension Crashes When Installed From Webstore - Need To Identify Cause of Crash

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, crash, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-web-store

I have a google chrome extension that crashes after you install it from the webstore. When installed from a local copy the extension does not crash. The crash happens when you click the tool bar icon that is added once it has been installed. The icon is supposed to load a table with URLs. Once restarted all you get is the option to recover tabs. I was hoping someone could help identify the issue of the crash or tell me how to access a crash report to see what is causing the problem.

The extension is located here: 
[Chrome Store App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bidpanther-for-quibids-fr/bgffajcgoafmnanflddpjnbjkhnfagdc)

Any help or direction will be very appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? Are you using Windows/Mac/Linux/Chrome OS? What do you mean by "crash"? Is the extension process terminated and does a bubble show up? Is Chrome itself crashing? If possible, could you show any video that produces the bug? And if you've gathered this information, please open a new issue at https://crbug.com/new, because this clearly sounds like a bug rather than a Chrome extension development issue.

Comment: The popup opens and then Chrome disables the extension and displays the error `This extension may have been corrupted.` on the extensions page.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I am using chrome version 39.0.2171.99 m which I think is the latest. I've tested on multiple versions, Win7 home, Win7 busines, windows 2008 r2 and all get the same issue. Google chrome crashes completely and has to be restarted. On Win7 home I get the option to debug using visual studio. I'll attach those files, but I don't know what to look for there.

I can shoot a video and happy to do so, but I'm not sure it will say much. I click the too bar icon and chrome goes away. Then I restart and it asks if I want to restore tabs.

Comment: Here is a video of Chrome crashing using the extension.
http://youtu.be/-GYdI5TEEw4
Notice when the same extension is loaded from the hard drive there is no problem. The problem only exists when installed from webstore. I've tried reverting back to old versions and I still have the problem which leads me to believe maybe a chrome update caused this?

Comment: I've dune more testing and realized the issue lies with the html of the popup. Tried with just the html with scripts disabled and still got the crash.  Then I tried with a basic html file with minimal code and it worked.  So is there a requirement of guidelines for popup.html for chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to a broken url in one of the css files.  By disabling all scripts  and  css we were able to find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I've looked into your issue, and there are two issues here:

1. Your extension gets disabled, "This extension may have been corrupted."
2. Chrome crashes.

The latter is caused by a bug that [has been fixed in Chrome 40](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=443177), so I'll only focus on the first issue.

The first issue is caused by Content Verification, an (experimental) security feature in Chrome that ensures the integrity of extensions from the Chrome web store, by disabling extensions that have become corrupted <sup>[crbug.com/369895](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=369895)</sup>. Corruption is detected by verifying the checksum of a file whenever an extension file is accessed by Chrome (for files referenced in the manifest file: at install-time; for other (embedded) files: when the file is loaded).

Unfortunately, there are some bugs in the implementation that causes extensions to be disabled in the following circumstances as well:

- [crbug.com/439464](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=439464) - The spelling of a filename in does not match the spelling of the path. On Windows and some Mac systems, the filesystem is case-sensitive, so during development, you may not notice that the spelling of the filename is incorrect. Content verification is case-sensitive, so it will treat "icon.png" different from (uppercase) "Icon.png".
  (This discrepancy in checks is unfortunate, but a good thing: if you use an incorrect spelling in the [`icons` field](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons), then the extension would not load on case-sensitive filesystems such as those commonly used on Linux.)
- [crbug.com/444085](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444085) - The paths are not resolved into a canonical form. When you use two "//" instead of "/", then Chrome will find the file, but not its corresponding checksum and disable the extension. To fix this, change "path//to/file" to "path/to/file". Fixing static paths (e.g. in HTML and CSS files) is relatively easy, but if you construct the paths dynamically, then finding the culprit becomes *much* harder.

To find out why your extension gets disabled, follow the instructions at [crbug.com/444085#c25](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444085#c25).