# My Chrome Extension Keeps Saying Its Corrupted

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I recently got a Chrome Developer account, i paid the 5 bucks and stuff. I published my extension after extensive testing and it works perfectly, but after i uploaded the app and then downloaded it to test it, whenever i try to open it, it disappears from my chrome bar and then when i check my extensions it says it may be corrupted, i tested this without it on the chrome store and it works fine, iv tried re-uploading it and everything, nothings working. I paid 5 dollars to be able to do this and i want to be able to upload my first extension, please help. heres the link to the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/its-raining-tacos-music-p/cnnefnjodgecgoncbgaeepfmmcjpchek

Comment: Try changing `Icon.png` in popup.html to `icon.png`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/28047758.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It because you're hitting an edge case bug in Google which verifies at run time that the contents inside an extension on disk match what was uploaded to the web store (designed to prevent malicious software from spoofing legitimate extensions).

Three known such bugs are:

[crbug.com/437675](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437675) (dot-slash paths in content scripts)

[crbug.com/439464](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=439464) (incorrect case in img tag injected by content-script)

[crbug.com/444085](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444085) (having // instead of / as an interior separator inside a url)

Please look through all the details and correct your code properly. For example, for my experience with this issue I was running into crbug.com/444085 by ends up generating requests to at least two urls with double-slashes in them:

images//arrow.png

images//popup.png

Then I modified the lines in the "script.js" file where has script like:

```
....  imgURL + '/arrow.png'   ....

....  imgURL + '/popup.png'   ....
```

Since `imgURL` already has a trailing slash in each case. Then the issue was fixed. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! My problem was i had my icon URL as "Icon.png" when the file was called "icon.png", never new a capital letter would be so bad :P

Comment: I saw a similar problem. I was using a graphic design program that exported images with the file extension .PNG  instead of .png
Changing the extensions to lower-case fixed the issue