# Images won't load in Chrome Extension when installed via ChromeStore

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension in webstore for several months now, and it has been working flawlessly. Recently, I changed the UI and added several new images in the extension. I have added the image folder in the "web_accessible_resources" property in the manifest file. `"src/lib/imgs/*"`

Problem is:When a user installs the extension via Chrome store, some images failed to load, and I have no idea why. All the images are in same folder. Some works and some does not. I myself have Chrome developers edition.

I am pretty sure all images were uploaded fine. I have chrome Version 43.0.2357.134 dev-m and when I install it from chrome webstore, it works fine. However when I install the same plugin on my different laptop that has chrome Version 43.0.2357.134 m.

By using this plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog I could see the source file of my extension in the chrome store and all files are there.

Does anyone have any suggestion or any idea what might be the issue here? Please let me know if my question is not clear or if you need more info to understand this issue.

Here is the beta version if you wanna try the plugin: chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpacflpjhonhpgpjkbilfblopejajlai/ (you can signup using any fake email address) - Please note once the issue is resolved i will have this beta version removed from the store.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 4 days of research I came across this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30715572/2241100

Since, my chrome extension was not pointing me to the right direction I had to manually go through each line and execute the script in my head and eventually I found this line in popup.js

```
$('#atomic_insights').attr('src', chrome.extension.getURL("src/lib/imgs//atomicinsights.png"));
```

I was lucky enough to notice the double slash (//) before the filename. And that was it!

Now, I am wondering why this piece of code worked in the developer mode? Why it did not throw the same error in the developer mode when I had this installed from locally? Why Chrome never pointed me to the right file and line number about this error. Is this a bug with the Chrome or is there some other explanation?

I do not have an answer to any of these questions above. Since I have found the bug I am gonna move forward and with the development. Thanks again @ZigMandel and @Xan for all the help.

Comment: the explanation as to why it worked in dev is in your linked answer. that chrome check is done only on published extensions otherwise there is nothing in the store to compare against.

Answer (score 1):

to be sure you should list your files and manifest but ill make a guess: you might have inconsistent case in your image names. because files have different case rules in different OSs it could work on some but byt others.
try setting all your image names in lowercase in the files and in the source references. also make sure you arent used reserved  characters. check for windows mac and Linux special character rules.

Comment: Indeed case seems to be the case (excuse the pun). It's inconsistent across files.

Comment: Thanks Zig and Xan for replying. I renamed all the files and reference to them to lower case but I still face same issue.. Here is how it looks in the console: 

`GET chrome-extension://cpacflpjhonhpgpjkbilfblopejajlai/src/lib/imgs/aw_audienceheart_knowledge.png net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: here is the directory structure and manifest: http://pastebin.com/cQsnBfYw

Here is how I am adding all the images in content_script.js file, several works except few.
`$('#aw_idealaud').attr('src', chrome.extension.getURL("src/lib/imgs/aw_audienceheart_knowledge.png"));`

Comment: @ZigMandel @Xan My answer below did not really the solution. Even when I fixed that, it still crashing. However, I notice that couple seconds after I click the browser action icon (on top right) to crashed. On `chrome://extensions` it says "This extension may have been corrupted" and that is when it fails to load image. Anything else you guys can think of?

Comment: Did you try to change files within an installed extension? That can happen then.

Comment: No @Xan I did not. I simply installed it from chrome store and try to use it and it crashes right away. In my local it works fine!

Comment: resample images to png to discard image corruption

Comment: being png does not mean they could be corrupted.

Comment: By using breakpoints I discovered that its not the png or images that causes the trouble. Plugin crashes or go in corrupt state even before it calls the images. Problem reside somewhere else, and I have no idea where to look now. I am literally going through each file and see if I can find something. I found few HTML and CSS errors, but that did not solve it. Still looking. let me know if you guys ( @Xan ) have any suggestions. thanks

Comment: can't suggest because now its too open even if you show the code.

Comment: @AR_HZ Maybe it's time to reboot the question. Make a new one, narrowing it down to your new findings.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found the issue while posting comments for Zig Mandal.

Take a look at the failed image I posted here.
`GET chrome-extension://cpacflpjhonhpgpjkbilfblopejajlai/src/lib/imgs/aw_audiencehear‌​t_knowledge.png net::ERR_FAILED`

When I tried to convert the file name `aw_audiencehear‌​t_knowledge.png` into ascii valule. I discovered that there is some sort of hidden character right after 'r' in the word 'heart'.

Copy paste the filename in http://asciivalue.com/index.php and you will see it.

I am not sure what type of character that is. Its purely invisible, its not a regular space tho. I am going to inspect all the filenames and see if there are any hidden characters and remove them one by one. I will update this once I completely resolve this.

If you guys have any information regarding this, please update this post.

Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: FYI: above solution did not solve the initial problem.