# How to solve chrome extension corrupt install which only occurs for some users?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, corrupt, manifest.json

I have a chrome extension "[RevNote Highlighter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revnote-highlighter-web-p/hiidedlcgggnjfkfhnmmhheffbllilic)" which is occasionally running into installation corrupt issues for some users.  I have never come across this when installed locally or when I have installed from Chrome Web Store.

I would like to know how to avoid this problem and also whether it is possible to be notified when users are unable to install my extension.

At first, I thought this might have been a file naming issue.  I had read this stackoverflow post about some common bugs and made sure that my extension was not hitting any of these issues. [My Chrome Extension Keeps Saying Its Corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699914/my-chrome-extension-keeps-saying-its-corrupted?rq=1)

I then decided to try and install the extension using Chromium on Windows using the following command from the Run (Windows + R) menu.

```
chrome --extension-content-verification=enforce --enable-logging --v=1 --vmodule=metrics=2
```

When I take a look at the `chrome_debug.log` I can see that there seems to be some kind of issue with the 4 files that are included in the `manifest.json`.

```
[89292:87248:0507/144820.424:VERBOSE1:content_hash.cc(296)] content mismatch for assets/r-clipper-action-16-blue.png
[89292:87248:0507/144820.424:VERBOSE1:content_hash.cc(296)] content mismatch for assets/r-clipper-action-32-blue.png
[89292:87248:0507/144820.425:VERBOSE1:content_hash.cc(296)] content mismatch for assets/r-clipper-action-48-blue.png
[89292:87248:0507/144820.426:VERBOSE1:content_hash.cc(296)] content mismatch for assets/r-clipper-icon-128.png
[89292:87248:0507/144820.429:VERBOSE1:content_hash.cc(296)] content mismatch for manifest.json
```

```
"icons": {
      "16": "assets/r-clipper-action-16-blue.png",
      "32": "assets/r-clipper-action-32-blue.png",
      "48": "assets/r-clipper-action-48-blue.png",
      "128": "assets/r-clipper-icon-128.png"
   },
```

I cannot find anything wrong with the paths of these files.  When I install the extension either on Chrome as per normal or using this Run command on chromium, the icon is correctly shown during the install process indicating that the system is locating the files without issue.

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome or an interoperability issue due to some antivirus.

Comment: I have tried to find reports of a bug related to this and there are a few which related to file path names.  Doesn't seem to be hitting any of these bugs.  However, most reports of similar issues on the web seem to point to issues with the icon files in the manifest.

Comment: I have the same issue but instead of icons, it cannot find the content scripts. Have you managed to solve the issue?